# problem in class-based views in django SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm following django 2.1 tutorial, based on this link  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/
 Here is my Code for books/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
from book.views import BookListView

app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index')
    path('list/', BookListView.as_view(template_name="media/templates/book/book_list.html")),
]
```

Below is my book/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Author, Book, BookInstance, Genre

from django.views.generic import ListView

def index(request):
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact = 'a').count()
    num_author = Author.objects.count()

    context = {
        'num_books' : num_books,
        'num_instances' : num_instances,
        'num_instances_available' : num_instances_available,
        'num_author' : num_author,
    }
    return render(request, 'book/index.html', context) 

class BookListView(ListView):
        model = Book
```

Error I'm getting is

> File "E:\DJango\mysite\book\urls.py", line 8
>       path('list/', BookListView.as_view(template_name="media/templates/book/book_list.html")),
>
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't be storing templates in your media directory; those are two separate things.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you so much, I'm just fallowing a tutorial, in that tutorial did this...
Then how should I sort them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'), // missed a ,
    path('list/', BookListView.as_view(template_name="media/templates/book/book_list.html")),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to store html files is to create a folder named "templates" under your Django app. You may also add another folder inside the templates folder with the same name as you app.

That way you can just call this file in your `urls.py` like this:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
from book.views import BookListView

app_name = 'book'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index')
    path('list/', BookListView.as_view(template_name="your_app_name/book_list.html")),
]
```

If you only created the "templates" folder, you can do this:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
    from . import views
    from book.views import BookListView

    app_name = 'book'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name = 'index')
        path('list/', BookListView.as_view(template_name="your_app_name/book_list.html")),
    ]
```

You may also call which template you are using inside your class based view:

```
class BookListView(ListView):
        model = Book
        template_name = 'your_app_name/book_list.html'
```

Or with only the "templates" folder:

```
class BookListView(ListView):
            model = Book
            template_name = 'book_list.html'
```